# wordpress hook issue for registration_redirect

Tags: wordpress

I am new in WordPress and struggling to use registration_redirect hook. i want to do for registration redirect after successful registration. Actually i have used

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'redirect_for_payment', 10, 1);
function redirect_for_payment(){ ".....Here i want to put another custom code before redirect....";}
```

But it's not working Please help.

What i Need exactly is i want that when user comes to registration page they will fill his information and when they submit form all process will happen same as default WordPress but after sending registration notification i want to stop execution and send user to another page.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? What happens? Error messages? What "custom code" do you want to put?

Comment: `registration_redirect` runs when `wp-login.php?action=register` loads via GET. Once the user hits the `register` button (POST), the filter does nothing. You can add a hidden field `redirect_to` with a URL as value to your form and WP will redirect to that URL upon successful registration.

Comment: actually what i have to do.. when user will register himself through the site successfully after hit on submit button default message will display to check mail for activation but i want to stop displaying message and when the page is redirecting after registration i have to post another form to other page. Steps what i am doing: 1. user fill information on registration page. 2. AFTER post the form let them to register and let send mail. 3. after send mail stop execution of the page and post other form to other page with the same post data filled by user on registration page.